# c# zip file - Extract file last

Tags: c#, zip

Quick question: I need to extract zip file and have a certain file extract last.

More info: I know how to extract a zip file with c# (fw 4.5).
The problem I'm having now is that I have a zip file and inside it there is always a file name (for example) "myFlag.xml" and a few more files.

Since I need to support some old applications that listen to the folder I'm extracting to, I want to make sure that the XML file will always be extract the last.

Is there some thing like "exclude" for the zip function that can extract all but a certain file so I can do that and then extract only the file alone?

Thanks.

Comment: Show us your looping unzip code, and I'll show you. :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the zip libraries in question, but I suspect you may be able to list the contents of the archive and then individually extract those contents in any order you like.

Comment: @oOo, I am just using:  ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath); This extract all.

Comment: @ZoRo, I've posted an answer. Try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably try a foreach loop on the `ZipArchive`, and exclude everything that doesn't match your parameters, then, after the loop is done, extract the last file.

Something like this:

```
    private void TestUnzip_Foreach()
    {
        using (ZipArchive z = ZipFile.Open("zipfile.zip", ZipArchiveMode.Read))
        {
            string LastFile = "lastFileName.ext";

            int curPos = 0;
            int lastFilePosition = 0;
            foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in z.Entries)
            {
                if (entry.Name != LastFile)
                {
                    entry.ExtractToFile(@"C:\somewhere\" + entry.FullName);
                }
                else
                {
                    lastFilePosition = curPos;
                }
                curPos++;
            }
            z.Entries[lastFilePosition].ExtractToFile(@"C:\somewhere_else\" + LastFile);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That looks great. So after I will run that, I can use "archive.GetEntry("myFile.xml")" To get only my XML. Thanks!

Comment: [ZipArchive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN